# parsing php multidimensional array to javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Voila, my problem: 
my PHP variable is a multidimensional array

```
var_dump($php_data);
```

result:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(5) { ["grey"]=> string(3) "aaa" ["black"]=> string(3) "bbb" ["blue"]=> string(3) "ccc" ["green"]=> string(3) "ddd" ["yellow"]=> string(3) "eee" ["brown"]=> string(3) "fff" }
[1]=> array(5) { ["grey"]=> string(3) "ggg" ["black"]=> string(3) "hhh" ["blue"]=> string(3) "iii" ["green"]=> string(3) "jjj" ["yellow"]=> string(3) "kkk" ["brown"]=> string(3) "lll" }
[2]=> array(5) { ["grey"]=> string(3) "mmm" ["black"]=> string(3) "nnn" ["blue"]=> string(3) "ooo" ["green"]=> string(3) "ppp" ["yellow"]=> string(3) "qqq" ["brown"]=> string(3) "rrr" } 
}
```

I want to extract only some value:

```
foreach (...as... =>...){
  ...
}
var js_array = echo json_encode(...);
```

to get a javascript array:

```
var js_array = [
  ['aaa', ccc, eee],
  ['ggg', iii, kkk],
  ['mmm', ooo, qqq],
];
```

I'm blocking in the loop ... 
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: You should show the code you have so far and tell us why it's not meeting your expectations. The intent of StackOverflow is to help you fix it, not simply write it for you.

Comment: thanks, I do not want any code, the loop is not clear for me ...
I am working to export a sharepoint list to js

Comment: How are you getting the data out of PHP into JavaScript? Say, if you have an Ajax call from the JavaScript client to the PHP server, PHP can convert the array to JSON and pass it down as a string. The Ajax in JavaScript can then JSON.parse that into a JavaScript object. Use "console.log()" to show what you got, then code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to define the keys you want (the values don't matter).

```
$keys = ['grey' => 1, 'blue' => 1, 'yellow' => 1];
```

Then use `array_intersect_key` on each row to get your result.

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[] = array_values(array_intersect_key($row, $keys));
}
```

`array_values` is needed there because if you still have the string keys, the  result of `json_encode` will be an array of objects rather than an array of arrays.

Comment: thanks, the important thing for my is the array of arrays in js, I do not have to "var js_array = echo json_encode(...);"